# Read a file and replace test after a certain word

Tags: c#, replace, find

I have a few files, for example:

```
FileBegin Finance  Open 87547.25 Close 548484.54 EndDay 4 End
```

Another file example:

```
FileBegin Finance  Open 344.34 Close -3434.34 EndDay 5 End
```

I need to read the text in the file and replace only the numeric value after the word Open leaving the rest of the text before and after the word Open intact. I have been using this code:

```
    string fileToRead = "c:\\file.txt";
    public void EditValue(string oldValue, string newValue, Control Item)
    {
        if (Item is TextBox)
        {
            string text = File.ReadAllText(fileToRead);
            text = text.Replace(oldValue, newValue);
            File.WriteAllText(activeSaveFile, text);
        }
     }
```

What would be the best way of going about replacing just the numeric value after the word `open`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using Regular Expressions:

```
Regex rgx = new Regex(@"Open [^\s]+");
string result = rgx.Replace(text, newValue);
File.WriteAllText(activeSaveFile, result );
```

Using this approach, you can store the regex object outside the method so you avoid recompiling it each time.  I'm guessing it won't have a significant performance impact compared to the file I/O in your case, but it is a good practice in other situations.

Answer (score 0):

Split the row by the empty spaces like `string.split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.Empty)` and then get the `_splittedRow[3]` and replace and merge the new row together.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you, the line:

```
FileBegin Finance  Open 344.34 Close -3434.34 EndDay 5 End
```

is the entire file? And you have been typing in "344.34" for the old value and "something" for the new value? And you'd like to  just type the new value only?

You could say:

```
string fileToRead = "c:\\file.txt";
public void EditValue(string oldValue, string newValue, Control Item)
{
    if (Item is TextBox)
    {
       string text = File.ReadAllText(fileToRead);
       string[] words = text.Split(new char[] {' '}); // assuming space-delimited
       words[3] = "new value";   // replace the target value
       text = "";
       foreach (string w in words)
       {
           text += w + " ";   // build our new string
       }
       File.WriteAllText(activeSaveFile, text.Trim());   // and write it back out
    }
}
```

That's a lot of ifs, but I think this is what you mean. Also there are a lot of different ways to replace that one part of the string, I just thought this would give you the flexibility to do other things with a convenient array of words.